# Archiving cloud stored files to speed up syncing

Tags: onedrive, archiving, cloud-storage

I have a lot of small files (50,000+) stored in OneDrive. Whenever I log into OneDrive on a new computer, it takes a long time for it to sync the files (without downloading).

Will it speed things up if I put these files into an archive? I hope that it might make it easier for OneDrive to index them.

Comment: Yes it does. 1 big file gets uploaded a lot faster than 10000 files that add up to the same size.

Comment: @Gantendo I was asking about syncing. It doesn't actually download or upload files

Comment: what do you think syncing does do?

Comment: @Gantendo tracks the changes. When you use OneDrive all your files appear in the file manager, but not all of them are actually stored on your computer.

Comment: It makes a list of files and checks for changes, but that should be a really quick process unless you have tens of thousands tiny files on a really slow old HDD. If that is the case, just buy an SSD. The uploading/downloading part of syncing is usually 99% of the time it actually does anything. But that is besides the point, indexing/downloading/creating/reading/uploading/whatever 1 file is faster than 10000 files, even if the file size is the same.

Comment: A single file will still be quicker to appear in the file manager than Onedrive having to create 50,000 sparse file links. Just because the data isn't downloaded doesn't mean that Onedrive isn't writing *something* to disk, those 50,000 files *are* created, just as empty files waiting for data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a single file will still be quicker to appear in the file manager than 50,000 smaller files.

Onedrive does dynamic downloading of data but still creates the "placeholder" for those files in the local filesystem using what is known as a [sparse file](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-sparse). The file is real, it exists, but the data is unallocated. It is not simply Onedrive taking a long while to "index" a big list of changes, it is making real changes to a local filesystem.

In your case instead of having to create 50,000 sparse file links Onedrive would create one single file.

Just because the data isn't downloaded doesn't mean that Onedrive isn't writing something to disk, those 50,000 files are created, just as empty files waiting to be filled with data.

Comment: which type of archive would you recommend? `tar.gz`?

Comment: It depends on your needs and where you are looking to send the file. 7Zip is a far better modern equivalent to `tar.gz` and even `tar.bz` would get better compression in most cases than `gz`. If you want compatibility with Linux and cannot install software yourself then `tar.gz` would be the most likely, if you need Windows compatibility and cannot install anything then probably `zip` would be better, otherwise if you *can* install software I would recommend `7z` with its LZMA2 algorithm for best compression. https://www.7-zip.org

Answer (score 0):

Try compressing small files in a compressed folder, OneDrive is slow to sync a large number of files.